# Old "double" book; one of the stories involves an alien childbirth, with the mother's womb and digestive system detaching from her body

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

Many years ago, I came across one of those "double" books, like the ones Ace and Tor used to publish. I don't recall the publisher, just that both stories were science fiction and that the book was a "tête-bêche" (i.e., inverted back-to-back).

One of the two stories (novellas?) involves a man falling for an alien woman, thrilled when she becomes pregnant; she is also happy but in a definitely bittersweet way, acting as if she won't be around much longer, making him promise to care for the child. He doesn't take her seriously until, finally, he is horrified to discover that in her species, childbirth involves the entire womb detaching from the mother's body, along with her digestive system - so that pregnancy automatically means the death of the mother within a few days, since she can no longer process nourishment.

I believe the second story was about an underwater civilization.

Anyone have a clue to identify the book or that first story?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a particularly viable breeding strategy unless births are multiple.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! It was probably around 20 years ago, and I had the impression that the book was already old... found it in a used bookshop, and remember thinking that the cover art felt more golden-agey than contemporary.

Comment: And yeah, it'd be a very efficient way to cut your population in half every generation... not exactly a recipe for biological success. Alas, the author was too busy with the emotional and, uh, visceral (literally) aspects of the situation to even attempt to play out the logic of the thing. Quite a bit of focus on the baby/expelled-womb combo as an object of horror - which of course now has to be fed by Dad, via Mom's former digestive organs.

Comment: @LuckyStarr While it's not the one you're looking for, this is unnervingly similar to the way vampire babies are born in Poppy Z. Brite's *Lost Souls*, with the baby cutting its way out of the mother's womb and causing a 100% maternal death rate in childbirth.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern It's practically a cliche for a half-monster/demon/vampire baby to kill its mother from inside.

Comment: ACE Doubles were published from 1952-1978, but only the tête-bêche from 52-73. Here is a Wiki page listing all Ace Doubles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ace_double_titles There may be another site for Tor Doubles.

Comment: You can also Google "Ace Doubles Cover" or "Ace Doubles science fiction cover) and see many images of covers and see if you spot one that looks familiar.

Comment: Tor Books published tête-bêche between 1988 and 1991

Comment: Childbirth reminiscent of Turtledove's *A World of Difference* but that does not seem to have been published in double novel format.